# How to start Zoom in background?

Tags: linux, fedora, zoom-meeting

I would like Zoom to start in the background (that is, its icon shows up in the system tray, while its window doesn't appear) right after the desktop environment is loaded.

On Windows, it is possible to get Zoom to start when the computer boots up just by ticking the "Start Zoom when I start Windows" checkbox in General, but this option is absent on Linux.

If I add `zoom` to autostart, it works but Zoom window appears on the screen and I have to close it on my own.

I know that to achieve similar behavior with Telegram I can just execute: `/opt/telegram/Telegram -startintray`. But I can't find a similar command to use for Zoom, although I found how to start/enter a meeting from the terminal and so on.

P.S.: I use Linux Fedora 33 KDE.

Comment: It would be best if there was a commandline switch similar to the one you show, but I'm wondering if a sequence of commands or a script that uses `wmctrl` or `xdotool` on the newly launched `zoom` GUI might actually minimize the window.

Comment: @rickhg12hs Thank you very much for your reply. Yes, I heard I can use xdotool or wmctrl to minimize/resize windows and do other similar tasks. But I wonder if I could hide the window to the taskbar, not just minimize it (although I'm going to take a look at these two, thank you for the advice).

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, Zoom still does not have any option to start in the tray.

To understand the script one needs to understand how Zoom starts up its UI:

First, Zoom launches a login window. If it remembers your credentials, it then logs you in, closes the login window, and launches the main window.

If the script closes the login window, Zoom will quit.  So the script waits for the main window to appear before attempting to close it.

I added a line to minimize the login window if not logged in (since it can't be closed without exiting Zoom), but then commented it out, given that one would probably want to keep it maximized in order to log in if it doesn't happen automatically.

The script checks for the main window 10 times, with a half-second delay between each check, for a total 5-second run time if not logged in. You can tweak the times checked based on your system by modifying `-lt 10`.  On my system, it takes 5 tries before it detects the main Zoom window. To determine how many tries it takes you, uncomment the echo statement before the first exit, and set the loop variable to that plus 1 or 2.

```bash
    #!/bin/sh
    # Launch zoom in the background
    zoom "$@" &
    
    # Check for zoom main window (10 tries with 0.5 secs between)
    HOSTNAME=`hostname`
    i=0
    FWID=
    while [ $i -lt 10 ]; do
        i=$((i+1))
        sleep 0.5
        wid=`wmctrl -l | grep -E " $HOSTNAME Zoom(\s|$)" | cut -d' ' -f1 | head -1`
        test -n "$wid" && {             # we got a window-id
            test "$wid" = "$FWID" || {  # that is not already found
                if [ -n "$FWID" ]; then # and is not the first (login) window
                    wmctrl -ic $wid     # close main window
                    #echo Took $i tries
                    exit 0
                else
                    FWID=$wid           # this is the first window found
                fi
            }
        }
    done
    # If we reach this point the main window did not come up so if there is a 
    # window found, we can elect to minimize it by uncommenting the next line:
    #wmctrl -ir $wid -b add hidden
    # (but I guess one would want to log in and then close it manually instead).
    exit 0
```

So, copy this script into your PATH, e.g. `/usr/local/bin/zoom-start-in-tray`, and make it executable:

```
chmod 0755 /usr/local/bin/zoom-start-in-tray
```

and you can use it to launch Zoom in the background, closing the window.

I launch the above script in the background in my `.xsession`, but if you want to use it as a desktop environment autostart you need to create an application file for it as well, e.g. `~/.local/share/applications/zoom-start-in-tray.desktop`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Zoom
Comment=Zoom Video Conference
Exec=/usr/local/bin/zoom-start-in-tray %U
Icon=Zoom
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF-8
Categories=Network;Application;
StartupWMClass=zoom
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/zoommtg;x-scheme-handler/zoomus;x-scheme-handler/tel;x-scheme-handler/callto;x-scheme-handler/zoomphonecall;application/x-zoom
X-KDE-Protocols=zoommtg;zoomus;tel;callto;zoomphonecall;
Name[en_US]=Zoom
```

If you want to use the system-wide desktop file, probably located in `/usr/share/applications/Zoom.desktop`, just change the `Exec` parameter to match the above.

Comment: I came in here reading expecting some dmb-a$$ answer.  NICE ANSWER! :) +1